# multiple operations of columns and a single scan SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, performance

I have a table with **200 columns (maybe more...)**

```
a1   a2   a3     a4  a5  ...a200
---------------------------------
1.2  2.3  4.4   5.1  6.7... 11.9   
7.2  2.3  4.3   5.1  4.7... 3.9   
1.9  5.3  3.3   5.1  3.7... 8.9   
5.2  2.7  7.4   9.1  1.7... 2.9
```

I would like to compute many operations:

- SUM(every column)
- AVG(every column)
- **SQRT(SUM(every column))**
- **POWER(SUM(every column),2)**
- **MIN(all columns)**
- **MAX(all columns)**
- **GREATEST(SUM(one column) vs SUM(other column))** 
  something like finding wich sum is greatest for every column:

  ```
  a1 vs a2,  a1 vs a3, a1 vs a4....,a1 vs a200,
  a2 vs a1,  a2 vs a3, a4 vs a5....,a2 vs a200,  
  ...
  a200 vs a1, a200vs a2, a200vs a3.....a200 vs a199
  ```

If I do a single select statement for each column,and for each operation I'd have:

```
SELECT 
 SUM(a1),...,SUM(a200),
 AVG(Sum(a1)),...,AVG(Sum(a200)),
 POWER(Sum(a1),2),...,POWER(Sum(a200),2),
 GREATEST(SUM(a1),SUM(a2)), GREATEST(SUM(a1),SUM(a3)),...,GREATEST(SUM(a1),SUM(a200)),
 GREATEST(SUM(a2),SUM(a1)), GREATEST(SUM(a2),SUM(a3)),...,GREATEST(SUM(a2),SUM(a200))....
 GREATEST(SUM(a200),SUM(a1)), GREATEST(SUM(a200),SUM(a3)),...,GREATEST(SUM(a200),SUM(a199))
 etc... FROM tabMultipleColumns
```

The problem here is when I do a query with more than 1024 possible results
aka, >= 1024 columns

Is there a way to keep doing massive operations with data **doing a single scan of the table**, I mean avoiding doing multiple selects statements?

> I am trying to use only a scan, because if the table is huge (with size
>   of many GB's) using many selects statements to scan the same table would be expensive...

Can a tool like `BCP` be used or what solution do you think is more efficient...

if you look only for the SUM, POWER(SUM(),2) and SQRT(SUM()), there are `600` result columns... if I keep doing this operations there are more than 1024...

Comment: Where is the result of this query ultimately going to be used? Can it be fed to an application outside the context of SQL Server, or is someone going to need to consume this from within Management Studio, or an application calling a stored procedure, that kind of thing? Also, are users really going to need to see all 1024+ columns every time?

Comment: To access the information, the ordinal number is used, so if I query ordinal number 1 to 200 I would retrieve The results of SUMS(), if I query 201 to 400 it means I am asking AVG() etc... but all results are requiered each time.

Comment: Neither SQRT() nor POW() are aggregate functions.  They cannot be used in this way, nor in any similar way that makes sense.  It really seems like you're just throwing out random functions here without a clear idea of what you really need.

Comment: ah sorry, you caught me there, I fixed the question so you get the idea, I FORGOT TO INCLUDE THE `SUM` INSIDE AS I DID FOR `GREATEST(SUM(a1),SUM(a2))`

Comment: In fact POW() isn't even a legal function in SQL Server, perhaps you mean POWER()?  It needs two arguments though, not one.  And it's still not an aggregate function, so maybe you could provide some clarification on what your really need to accomplish here?

Comment: What I meant is this:   to do multiple operations in a huge dataset... and to do in the most efficient way, so, I need to do several operations by column, but as the number of columns increase when there are more than 200 columns, the single big query that scans the table once will not fit in the result as SQL can only return a row with 1024 columns... And I am planning to get more than 1024 results (operations with data) and **most important, scan the table once because is really huge, like > 10 GB**

Comment: Max number of columns for a select statement is not 1024 it is 4096 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx. Perhaps that is enough?

Comment: The only options I can think of are streaming all the data to your application and doing the calculations manually outside of SQL, or using some form of procedures in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a lot of calculations. I would probably just do a periodic dump of them into another table to minimize server load. It depends on how often the query is going to be used though.

Comment: And to keep things efficient... how to follow your idea?

Comment: That depends. How current does the data need to be?

Comment: Well the most current as possible